# Regex get index of first character not inside double quotes

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I am looking for a regex to do the following:

- Return the index of the first instance of a given character not inside double quotes (I can guarantee a matching closing double quote will always be present and the character to search for will never itself be a double quote)
- Allow starting from `int startIndex` position

Speed is one of my primary concerns here so the number of iterations should be as small as possible.

Examples (all examples set to look for `!`, but this might not always be the case):

- `!something` - should return 0
- `!` should also return 0
- `something!` should return 9
- `"something!"` should fail
- `"some!thing"!` should return 12
- `!"!"!` should return 0
- `""!` should return 2
- `""!""` should return 2
- `!something` with `startIndex == 2` should fail
- `!something!` with `startIndex == 2` should return 10 (despite starting at position 2, the index of the character on the given string is still 10)

Since this is for .NET the intention is to use `Regex.Match().Index` (unless a better alternative is provided).

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working? Have you tried a simple solution using for or string.IndexOf?

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea I have tried a solution using a `for`, am looking to make some comparisons between it and a regex. Have not found any suitable regexes and my own knowledge of them is rusty.

Comment: what should be the output for - word = !"some!thing"!  , start index 5 ?

Comment: @AnuViswan it should be 13

Comment: (!)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)

Comment: But I have to agree with Dmitry on this, I think regex is overkill for this

Answer (score 1):

I suggest good old `for` loop instead of *regular expressions*; let's implement it as an extension method:

```
  public static partial class StringExtensions {
    public static int IndexOfQuoted(this string value,
                                    char toFind,
                                    int startPosition = 0,
                                    char quotation = '"') {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return -1;

      bool inQuotation = false;

      for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i)
        if (inQuotation)
          inQuotation = value[i] != quotation;
        else if (value[i] == toFind && i >= startPosition)
          return i;
        else
          inQuotation = value[i] == quotation;

      return -1;
    }
  }
```

And so, you can use it as if `IndexOfQuoted` a `string`s method:

```
  string source = "something!";
  int result = source.IndexOfQuoted('!');
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "!something",
    "!",
    "something!",
    "\"something!\"",
    "\"some!thing\"!",
    "!\"!\"!",
    "\"\"!",
    "\"\"!\"\"",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-20} -> {test.IndexOfQuoted('!')}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
!something           -> 0
!                    -> 0
something!           -> 9
"something!"         -> -1
"some!thing"!        -> 12
!"!"!                -> 0
""!                  -> 2
""!""                -> 2
```

Comment: I already have a method that cycles through every character in the string (and is more efficient than this one), but am curious to see what a regex to do the same would look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need regex version, you could use a pattern as follows.

```
"(?<searchTerm>!)(?=(?:[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*$)"
```

Example, for input

```
var input = new []
    {
    new {Key= "!something", BeginIndex=0},
    new {Key= "!", BeginIndex=0},
    new {Key= "something!", BeginIndex=0},
    new {Key= "\"something!\"", BeginIndex=0},
    new {Key= "\"some!thing\"!", BeginIndex=0},
    new {Key= "!\"!\"!", BeginIndex=0},
    new {Key= "\"\"!", BeginIndex=0},
    new {Key= "\"\"!\"\"", BeginIndex=0},
    new {Key= "!something", BeginIndex=2},
    new {Key= "!something!", BeginIndex=2},
    new {Key="!\"some!thing\"!",BeginIndex=5}
    };
```

You can search Index as follows

```
var pattern = "(?<searchTerm>!)(?=(?:[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*$)";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach(var str in input)
{
    var index = str.Key.GetIndex(regex,str.BeginIndex);
    Console.WriteLine($"String:{str.Key} , Index : {index}");
}
```

Where GetIndex is defined as

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static int GetIndex(this string source,Regex regex,int beginIndex=0)
    {
        var match = regex.Match(source);
        while(match.Success)
        {   

            if(match.Groups["searchTerm"].Index >= beginIndex)
                return match.Groups["searchTerm"].Index;

            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Output

```
String:!something , Index : 0
String:! , Index : 0
String:something! , Index : 9
String:"something!" , Index : -1
String:"some!thing"! , Index : 12
String:!"!"! , Index : 0
String:""! , Index : 2
String:""!"" , Index : 2
String:!something , Index : -1
String:!something! , Index : 10
String:!"some!thing"! , Index : 13
```

Hope that helps.